# Is it possible to use two icons in css content one below other

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a css class like below

```
.fa-unsorted:before, .fa-sort:before {
    content: '\e9c2';
    margin-top: -10px;
    color: #999999;
    font-family: 'icomoon';
}
```

It displays following

[image]

What I want is to also include `\e9c1` as well but it should be displayed below `\e9c2`.

For context, I am using a library that has the css class mentioned to display sort icon. It uses fa-sort which has both up and down arrow in the same icon.

[image]

But I am using icomoon which does not have that kind of replacement. So I need to use two icons to display a sort. Following is what I want

[image]

I tried following for content, but as expected the arrows get displayed next to each other.

```
content: '\e9c2\e9c1';
```

Adding another class would be nice, but I don't have control on the JS to add new class.

Comment: Have you tried to add your down arrow to `.fa-sort:after`?

Comment: @RichardCasetta That would produce the same result as `content: '\e9c2\e9c1';`.

Comment: Right. It produced the same result as setting both in single content.

Comment: Ok visually it's the same, but you have more control over it. Indeed, you can now chose to put the `.fa-sort:after` in an absolute positioning to place it wherever you want

Comment: @TechCrunch Can you please add fiddle of you issue?

Comment: I thought I won't be able to use after at all, like if it has to be added by JS. I guess its working but trying some changes. Will report back

Comment: Just use the embed icon `(ea7f)` and use `transform` to rotate the span element.

Comment: @Ricky transform did not work. Tried that already. May be I did something wrong. Also, it is little bit different from what I wanted, but will use is as last option. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add more than one to the :before pseudo element.

I'd recommend doing this if :after element is not already being used:

```
  .fa-unsorted:before, .fa-sort:before {
        content: '\e9c2';
        margin-top: -10px;
        color: #999999;
        font-family: 'icomoon';
    }

    .fa-unsorted:after, .fa-sort:after{
        content: '\e9c1';
        margin-top: -15px;
        color: #999999;
        font-family: 'icomoon';
        right:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use icomoon embed icon `(ea7f)` and use `transform` to rotate the `span` element, like so:

```css
.icon-embed--vertical {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.icon-embed::before {
  content: "◀▶";  /* Actual icon here: content: "\ea7f";*/
  font-size: .6em; /* styling */
}
```

```html
<button>Date Created <span class="icon-embed icon-embed--vertical"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use both pseudo for this, `:before` & `:after`, then style them as you wish, with arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Just use another pseudo element, i.e.: `::after`:

```
.my-icon::after,
.my-icon::before {
    color: #999;
}

my-icon::after {
    content: '\e9c1';
}

my-icon::before {
    content: '\e9c2';
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

P.s. pseudo-elements, unlike psuedo-classes should have two double-colons, i.e.: ::after *not* :after. #justsayin